# Can you use other gamepass ids on your own Roblox game?

Tags: roblox

I'm creating a game on Roblox and I need to know if I can use other user's gamepass ids. And if I can will they work?

Comment: I see this question hasn't gotten any traction over the past day. You might be able to get more attention by editing your question to add more details about what you're trying to do / what game feature or workflow you're trying to create.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using another user's game pass id I don't think it will work out because only game passes created under your game will work in your game.

Edit: Only gamepasses from this page are available to use on your game:
`https://www.roblox.com/develop?selectedPlaceId="`**`yourgameid`**`"&View=34`